# jquery code not working in aspx

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to have a text box where as the user types in the text box the label below reads how many characters are left using jquery.

When i tried the jquery code below in regular html page it worked as expected.. but when I try to do it in my aspx page it wont update the label.

I am a beginner to jquery so I am not sure if I am missing something here.. Can someone please guide me in the right direction..

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPageToolkitScriptManager.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="DotNet_test" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="WebUserControl" 
    Src="~/Controls/WebUserControl.ascx" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderHead" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderBody" Runat="Server">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('<%= inp1.ClientID %>').keyup(function () {
            var x = $('<%= inp1.ClientID %>').val().length;
            //alert(x);
            var y = 10;
            $('<%= p1.ClientID %>').text("Len balance : " + (y - x));

            if ((y - x) < 0) {
                $('<%= p1.ClientID %>').html("too much");
                $('<%= inp1.ClientID %>').val($('<%= inp1.ClientID %>').val().substring(0, 10));
            }

        });

    });
 </script>

    <asp:TextBox ID="inp1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Label ID="p1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

<%--<input id="inp1">
<button id="b1">Click</button>
<p id="p1"></p>--%>


    </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a normal jQuery ID-based selector:

```
$("#myElementID");
```

Now, take a look at your selector:

```
$('<%= inp1.ClientID %>')
```

You've lost the `#`, which is what tells jQuery that you're looking for an *ID* and not a *node type*. Because of this, your selectors aren't finding anything.

Change your selectors to include the `#`, like so:

```
$('#<%= inp1.ClientID %>')
```

And you should be all set!

---

**Alternative answer:**

Take a look at this Textbox:

```
<asp:Textbox runat="server" id="MyTextbox" ClientIDMode="static"></asp:Textbox>
```

Notice how I've added `ClientIDMode="static"`. This tells ASP to render the control *without altering the ID at all*. This means you can simply use the selector `$("#MyTextbox")` in your jQuery, and it will find the textbox.

**NOTE:** Do *not* use this on elements that are within a repeating container, like GridViews or Repeaters. Because ID's must be unique, if you are going to have duplicates of this textbox, you need the IDs to be different. In such a scenario, consider using `ClientIDMode="predictable"`, which instead appends an index to your ID like `MyTextbox1`, `MyTextbox2`, etc.

Comment: @psj01 Another piece of advice: If you're not using elements that will repeat (like inside gridviews or repeaters), note that there is an ASP condition called `ClientIDMode`. If you set this to `static`, then the ClientID will render **exactly** as you declare it in ASP. So for example, a textbox with `id="myTextBox" ClientIDMode="static"` will actually render on the page with the ID `myTextBox`. No need for server tags in your jQuery anymore!

Comment: also, if you dont mind me asking.. why do I need the " $(document).ready(function () { } " and have the key up code inside it.. If i dont have that it wont work..

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that.  I am just learning jquery from scratch.. :)

Comment: `document.ready` tells your code to wait until the page is finished loading. The line after that tells your code "Find this element, and add this keyup event to it". However, if you don't wait for the page to load, the element hasn't loaded yet, and so when you say "Add the keyup event to **such-and-such** element", that **such-and-such** element doesn't exist yet - it hasn't loaded! Thus, no event will be applied c:

Comment: I just rewrote the code with ClientIDMode turned to static and it worked. Thats much nicer to work with. Thanks a  lot.

Comment: As one more note, I would move all your `<script>` tags (the jquery insert, and the code itself) into your `ContentPlaceHolderHead` instead of `ContentPlaceHolderBody`.